# Using java calculate the area of the circle

Tags: java

Implement a program to find the area of a circle by using the formula given below and display the calculated area . Area = pi* radius* radius.

Comment: Better advice.  Don't search for a solution.  Write the program yourself.  (I assume that you have been set this as a homework exercise to help you learn you to program.  If you just Google for a solution ... or ask for a solution here ... the person you are really cheating is yourself.  You are cheating yourself out of the opportunity to learn.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice , but I am really bad at building logics since I am an not an IT person :) .

Comment: Put it this way ... if you don't actually attempt to write the programs for yourself, you will never become an "IT person".  It is not something you can learn to do by watching other people.  (And one has to ask ... why would you be taking a course in programming if you don't have ambitions to learn programming?)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create a method like this,

```
public double findAreaOfCircle(double radius){
        return Math.PI*(Math.pow(radius,2));
}
```

So you need to call the method and pass the radius.